# Don't match the URL's between BBCode tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, bbcode

As the title says I want my pattern to match the URL's in the string, **except** the ones that are between the BBCode tags.

So far I have made a pattern that doesn't match the URL's between the `[img]` tags, but have no enough regex skills to make it work for all tags like the more advanced onces (`[url=xxx]yyy[/url]` and such). So to be clear: **nothing** between `[` and `]` should match.

---

Here is my *working example* to not match the URL's between the [img] tag:

http://regexr.com/v1?38mae (may have to paste the below pattern due to encoding being messed up)

Pattern:

`(?<!\[img])(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)|www\.)[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#!]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])`

**I'd appreciate any kind of help!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this at the begining of your pattern:

```
\[[^]]*](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|
```

This subpattern will find all that is between square brackets, make the pattern fail and force to not retry the substring.

Example with your pattern (with `~` as delimiter):

```
$pattern = '~\[[^]]*](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|
             (?<!\[img])
             (?:(?:ht|f)tps?://|www\.)
             [\w-]+
             (?:\.[\w-]+)+
             [\w-.,@?^=%&:/\~+#!]*[\w-@?^=%&/\~+#]~xiu';
```

Comment: Sound nice, but doesnt work for me for some reason. Could you place that on regexr?

Comment: @Cyclone: test it with real php code, not on a regex tester.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Wow, thats pretty genious. I dont get why doesnt it work on a regex tester though.

Comment: @Lucas: not all regex testers for PHP implements backtracking control verbs like `(*SKIP)` and `(*FAIL)`. However I know that http://regex101.com and http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com implement these features (be careful with delimiters if you test it).